# Redirecting ec2-****.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com URL to actual site URL

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I recently setup `wordpress` on a new domain in AWS and imported an old worpress site in it. Everything is working fine except URL. Whenever I type my site URL it redirects to correct address i.e. `www.example.com` but when I click on any post on the site, it redirects me to the `ec2-****.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/`.

How can i make sure that that after clicking any post it gets redirected to `www.example.com/post` not on `www.ec2-****.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/post`.

Here is what I have done so far:

- Added `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` to my `wp-config.php`
- Routed my domain through `route53`.

None: This question has been asked in stackoverflow but none of them worked for me. I am to a point where i want to chew my face.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: In Route53, you mentioned CNAME or Alias record for routing  ec2-****.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com ?

Comment: I used Alias for routing ec2-****.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: Can you change to CNAME to ec2-****.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried directly changing website in wordpress database, if not try following steps:

- Connect to you database wordpress database
- change option_value column in wp_options table for option_name siteurl

  UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'your.website.com' WHERE option_name = 'siteurl';

Hope this helps